# Why load stylesheets through JS?

Tags: html, css, webpack, webpack-style-loader

Webpack's homepage claims to compile all stylesheets and dependencies into a single CSS file but that's misleading. Not only do you need a separate loader for CSS, but it instead outputs as a JS file that loads then applies an embedded CSS string.

Why take the long route? There must be a good reason for doing that, right?

(I am aware of the extract text plugin, but that's not default behavior.)

Since JavaScript is executed synchronously, wouldn't this place penalties on displaying the content ASAP? Also, I'm able to see an unstyled page for a brief period before the style is finally loaded and applied.

**Why on earth would I want my styles loaded via JS when a simple CSS file is fine?**

Comment: Loaders have many functions. You can load URL instead of CSS string: `require("style/url!file!./file.css");`

Answer (score 0):

So in a system such as GULP, GULP is a Javascript task runner which can compile CSS and Javascript dependencies into singular files or multiple files depending on how you setup your build process.

Reasons for compiling CSS

- The ability to use a pre-processor like LESS or SASS
- Automate the minification of these assets for distribution.
- The ability to combine many CSS files into a single file to reduce the total requests on a page.
- The ability to add revision #'s to the end of a file to beat a caching system.

Reasons for compiling JS

- The ability to combine multiple scripts into a single script to
  reduce requests and file size.
- Automated minification.
- The ability to add revision #'s to the end of a file to beat a caching system.

Webpack sounds like a very backwards way to do these things.

Comment: I don't think I'm understanding this answer. I know the benefits of packing assets of a single type into a larger file of the same type, but what I don't understand is why webpack chooses to pack the CSS into JS. Concatenation, minification, and versioning are all things you can do with CSS, too.

Comment: Also, do you mean that using webpack for what I'm doing is backwards? Because I thought this was its intended purpose.